# How to make an image take up the rest of the available space automatically inside a 100vh container?

Tags: html, css

I have a container which has the height of `100vh`. It contains an image and some text. The height of the text can change based on the screen and text. I want the text to take up the space that it needs and the image should use the rest of the available space.

Here is my code. It is already what I want basically but I want to get rid of the `83vh`. The image should take the rest of the space dynamically. Is this possible?

Thank you guys!

PS: I added the Javascript tag because I'm not sure if a Javascript solution might be necessary.

```css
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center -180px;
    /* this height should be dynamically */ 
    height: 83vh
}

.text-wrapper {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://img.100r.systems/img/be10bc26de653473f80b4348addfc6b5.jpg">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h1>Some Text goes here</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this by using CSS grid. The two cells in the grid being of 1fr (ie as much space as is left) and auto in height.

This snippet also moves the img to be a background-image within a div, covering its cell and centered.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  rmax-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-image: url(https://img.100r.systems/img/be10bc26de653473f80b4348addfc6b5.jpg);
}

.text-wrapper {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <h1>Some Text goes here</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor <br>invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: for a completely general solution you need to decide what should happen if the text itself takes up more than the height of the viewport.

Comment: Thank you! That's an even better solution than mine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```css
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center -180px;
}

.text-wrapper {
    padding-left: 15px;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://img.100r.systems/img/be10bc26de653473f80b4348addfc6b5.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h1>Some Text goes here</h1>
        <p>I think it works now<br> and I'm very happy now<br>It works, right?
    </div>
</div>
```